# Code format helper?

Tags: xcode

Would like to ask is there a tool in xcode whereby it will check the code format and restructure it in such a way that its much more presentable? Sort of indenting helper, I suppose?

For example

```
            -(void)someMethod {
    switch(obj.someString)
{
...
}
}
```

Is there a helper to change it to

```
    -(void)someMethod {
    switch(obj.someString)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

also when the codes get really long, I want to break them down into different rows.

```
string = @"example1"; string2 = @"example2"; string3 = @"example3" ...;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i typically use  [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). both are open.

they each have a ton of options. they can add or remove spaces/braces/lines, pad, split, indent, hard wrap, force tab or space indentation and much more.

assuming you have macports, drop this into your terminal to install:

`sudo port install astyle`

`sudo port install uncrustify`

since both programs support multiple languages: you will probably want to use uncrustify for objc.

Answer (score 0):

right click in the .h or .m file.There it will displays the rightindent selection.click on that.